# Can we execute a shell script by clicking

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, command-line

Is it possible to double click and execute a shell script instead of executing the following "./xxxx.sh" notation from command prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Right click on the file, choose Properties, and then click on the Permissions Tab, and check Allow executing file as program.

[image]

[image]